# Entity Framework - DBContext - Not updating, possibly caching?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity, dbcontext

I have a strange problem that only happens intermittently and on only a couple of fields in my model.

The application is for booking courses, the administrator creates a course and then users apply.

Some tables which are simplified below.

Course

- CourseID
- CourseTitle
- CourseDetails

CourseDate

- CourseID
- CourseDateID
- CourseDate
- CourseVenueID
- CourseStatusID

Item

- ItemID (Holds VenueID/StatusID)
- ItemType
- ItemDescription

Sometimes when an administrator creates a new coursedate users viewing the dates on the front end are getting a null value on the CourseVenueID field. There is clearly a value in this field when I look in the database.

It seems though that If i restart the website in IIS the relationship is then formed and the site works ok...until an administrator adds another course.

This doesn't happen all the time however, and not on all fields. It does happen on another field within the application however, but again intermittently.

I'm using a repository and Unit of work however I have checked how the relationships etc are formed and cant see anything that might cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to answer because you did't provide a code that adds CourseDate and that shows data for user. But I can advice you some general steps that probably helps you find a solution:

- Add small pieces of adding and showing code here, so some one can point you on problems
- Look at problem code, and try to find solution analytically (ask yourself where data can be outdated)
- do you store a context some where?
- Is Add CourseDate operation fully in transaction with appropriate isolation level?
- Run database profiler and try to reproduce that situation, and then compare data step by step
- Add log of all insert/update/get operations of interest scope
- Add db history of interest entities